# Send array with ajax request to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created array like this `["9", "ques_5", "19", "ques_4"]`. Now I want to send it from JS to PHP but I'm not getting proper results. My JS code is:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'post', 
        cache   : false,
        url     : 'test/result.php',
        data    : {result : stuff},
        success: function(resp) {
            alert(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

In the above code `stuff` is an array which contains records. How can I send this array with above code and then in PHP I want to process this array like `ques_5` is the key and `9` become the value for that key.

Comment: you can use JSON.stringify() to pass that array to the php,then process it there according to your need

Comment: to post it to PHP, the array has to be of `key => value` type, and properly formatted, so it would look like... `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`

Comment: thanks all i have replace the code now it show array like {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}.Now again how to send it with post request ?

Comment: `data: stuff` to post it correctly if the ajax portion is calling the url correctly.

Comment: @Jon yeah it call correctly url but the parameters and source become undefined.

Comment: What does your PHP look like to retrieve them?

Comment: Now i am on the way . i got this array Array
(
    [0] => ques_5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => ques_4
    [3] => 11
)

Comment: but how can i get second portion.key => value ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can pass the data to the PHP script as a [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) object. Assume your JSON object is like:

```
var stuff ={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'};
```

You can pass this object to the php code in two ways:

**1. Pass the object as a string:**

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : 'result.php',
    data    : {result:JSON.stringify(stuff)},
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }    
});
```

You can handle the data passed to the `result.php` as :

```
$data    = $_POST["result"];
$data    = json_decode("$data", true);

//just echo an item in the array
echo "key1 : ".$data["key1"];
```

**2. Pass the object directly:**

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : 'result.php',
    data    : stuff,
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }    
});
```

Handle the data directly in `result.php` from `$_POST` array as :

```
//just echo an item in the array
echo "key1 : ".$_POST["key1"];
```

Here I suggest the second method. But you should try both :-)

Comment: Thanks in php i got this array Array ( [0] => ques_5 [1] => 10 [2] => ques_4 [3] => 11 ) .Now i want to divide this array into key and values.

Comment: are you sure `key` and `value` are alternative values of the array

Comment: k....then use this loop...`$i=0;
 $result=array();
 while($i<count($data)){
  $key = $data[$i++];
  $val = $data[$i++];
  $result[$key] = $val;
 }`....the `$result` array will contain what you needed....

Comment: hai. Can I send ajax post and send model form all at once?? give example

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send key value pairs, which is what I am seeing, it would be better to use a PHP JSON library (like this one... http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Then you can send actual key value pairs, using JSON format like...
    {"ques_5" : "19", "ques_4": "19"}

Comment: Correct on the second part.  For the first part, the key value pair would be converted to the array `$_POST['key'] = 'value'` when submitted to PHP, so the use of the library isn't beneficial unless reading JSON from an API or sending JSON to javascript, but most anything JS sends to PHP via an AJAX request will be converted to an array automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var array = ["9", "ques_5", "19", "ques_4"];
console.log(array.join(","));
```

above code will output string with comma separated like `9,ques_5,19,ques_4`then paste it to ajax call.

And then in `php explode` that string.

Other possible solutions.

**First**

```
var obj = { 'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2' };

$.ajax(
{
    type:  'post', 
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'test/result.php',
    data:  { result : JSON.stringify(obj) },
    success: function(resp)
    {
        alert(resp);
    } 
});
```

**Second**

```
var a = $.JSON.encode(obj);

$.ajax(
{
    type:  'post', 
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'test/result.php',
    data:  { result : a },
    success: function(resp)
    {
        alert(resp);
    } 
});

In PHP File

<?php
    $json = $_POST["data"]
    var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```

Comment: Won't work, or come close to it.  No data passed from javascript is in that format unless as a 'string' type.

Comment: just create one variable as var passString = array.join(","); and then in jQuery ajax data send it there.

Comment: This still won't index it properly for php without more code.  Better to fix the problem and submit proper data in the javascript portion.

Comment: i have added other possible solutions..please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the `array in json` format to the php and then use `json_decode` function to get back the array like

In ajax call you have to send json for that you need to first make array of the values so that you get it in right form 
so that you json look like `{"ques_5":"9","ques_4":19}`

and use in ajax call

```
 data: JSON.stringify(`your created json`),
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
```

IN PHP it look like

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a complete example that works for me in order to avoid making each JavaScript function for each PHP function

// on the HTML side a simple JavaScript call from a link

```
 <a href="javascript:CargaZona('democonllamada', 'tituloprin', {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'})" >test</a>
<div id='tituloprin' >php function response here!</div>
```

// on JavaScript side

```
function CargaZona(fc, div, params) {
    var destino = "#" + div;
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : "inc/phpfunc.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            fc : fc,
            params : JSON.stringify(params)
        },
        dataType : "html"
    });

    request.done(function (msg) {
        $(destino).html(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
}
```

// on phpfunc.php page

```
<?php

$params = "{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}"; 
$fc = 'def';
if (isset($_POST['fc']))   {    $fc = $_POST['fc']; }
if (isset($_POST['params']))   {    $params = $_POST['params']; }

switch ($fc) {
    default:
        call_user_func($fc,$params);
}

function democonllamada($params) {
    $params = json_decode("$params", true);
    echo "ok llegaron".$params['key1'];
}

?>
```