# Ajax Response Send to another page

Tags: php, ajax, cs-cart

I want to send ajax response to another page with an array value and i also don't want to show array value into URL. What should i do for this and sorry form my english.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: {dispatch:'products.validate',pro: id,}
              }).done(function( msg ) {
                      //alert(msg);
                      window.open('test.php?dispatch=products.url');

              });
```

Comment: use session for this set your values in session test.php and use window.location and get session values on another page

Comment: Thanks #RAkesh Sharma, is there any alternate?

Answer (score 2):

This qustion has already been asked in stackoverflow. you can find answer on the below link,

Check this out
[Send array with ajax request to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846496/send-array-with-ajax-request-to-php)